# "his eyes swam in his head"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> By degrees Rip’s awe and apprehension subsided. He even ventured, when no eye was fixed upon him, to taste the beverage, which he found had much of the flavor of excellent Hollands. He was naturally a thirsty soul, and was soon tempted to repeat the draught. One taste provoked another; and he reiterated his visits to the flagon so often that at length his senses were overpowered, **his eyes swam in his head**, his head gradually declined, and he fell into a deep sleep.

Could you describe in detail what "eyes swam in head" means so that I can picture it?

Is this a commonly used expression? When you want to describe a drunk person?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a commonly used expression. I take it to mean that he was rolling his eyes (not focusing on anything in particular) before he passed out.

Comment: It's [relatively uncommon today](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=eyes+swam+in+his+head%2Che+rolled+his+eyes&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ceyes%20swam%20in%20his%20head%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20rolled%20his%20eyes%3B%2Cc0), but a century or two ago it seems that ***eyes swam in his head*** was almost as common as ***he rolled his eyes***. But of course, nowadays, *rolling your eyes* usually implies being "exasperated" rather than glassy-eyed/woozy.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica A lot of the references Google finds seem to be from different editions of this very passage (from Washington Irving)!

Comment: there was also [*his brow paling and his **eyes swimming in the last dizzy gaze of death***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22eyes+swimming+in+the+last%22) doing the rounds backk then.